# Swift and Realm Error with Object Management

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm

I am using the Realm-Swift SDK to create some models but I am having an issue and I can’t work it out.

I have a class that is a top level “group”:

```
import RealmSwift

class InventoryGroup: Object, Identifiable, Encodable {
    @objc dynamic var id: UUID = UUID()
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @Published dynamic var sections: RealmSwift.List<InventorySection> = RealmSwift.List<InventorySection>()

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name,
           id,
           sections
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
      var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        
      try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
      try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
      try container.encode(sections, forKey: .sections)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(_ name: String) {
        super.init()

        self.id = UUID()
        self.sections = RealmSwift.List<InventorySection>()
        self.name = name
        return
    }

    func addSection(_ name: String) {
        sections.append(InventorySection(name))
    }
}
```

This then has sections (or a sub group):

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class InventorySection: Object, Identifiable, Encodable {
    @objc dynamic var id: UUID = UUID()
    var items: RealmSwift.List<InventoryItem> = RealmSwift.List<InventoryItem>()
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name,
           id,
           items
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }
    
    init(_ name: String) {
        super.init()
        self.id = UUID()
        self.items = RealmSwift.List<InventoryItem>()
        self.name = name
        return
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(items, forKey: .items)
    }

    func setupTest1() {
        self.items.append(InventoryItem("Sample Item 1"))
    }

    func setupTest2() {
        self.items.append(InventoryItem("Sample Item 2"))
    }
}
```

and then each section holds multiple items:

```
import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift

class InventoryItem: Object, Identifiable, Encodable {
    @objc dynamic var id: UUID = UUID()
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""
    @objc dynamic var notes: String = ""
    @Published dynamic var state: ItemState = .unchecked

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
      case name,
           id,
           state,
           notes
    }

    func setItemState(_ newState: ItemState) {
        self.state = newState
    }

    func encode(to encoder: Encoder) throws {
        var container = encoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)

        try container.encode(name, forKey: .name)
        try container.encode(id, forKey: .id)
        try container.encode(state, forKey: .state)
        try container.encode(notes, forKey: .notes)
    }

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    init(_ name: String) {
        super.init()
        self.id = UUID()
        self.name = name
        self.state = .unchecked
        self.notes = ""
    }

    enum ItemState: String, Encodable {
        case pass
        case fail
        case unchecked 
    }
}
```

in my ContentView I have a variable:

```
var inventoryGroup: InventoryGroup = .init("KV57P1")

let sec1 = InventorySection("Right Front")
sec1.setupTest1()
self.inventoryGroup.sections.append(sec1)
```

however this always produces error:

Terminating app due to uncaught exception ‘RLMException’, reason: ‘Only objects which are managed by a Realm support change notifications’

What am I missing with this, or what have I setup incorrectly.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Your issue is the same as in the linked duplicate target. You are never actually saving your objects to Realm, you are just creating a `List` as a local variable. You need to `write` your objects to Realm in order to store them and only then can you use Realm notifications.

Comment: I am with @DávidPásztor but wanted to add a little more clarity; If an object is instantiated in memory, it can be freely modified in any way you like. However, once it's written, it becomes a managed object and can only be modified within a `write` transaction. There are a couple of oddities in the code and the intention is not clear; `var items: RealmSwift.List<InventoryItem> = RealmSwift.List<InventoryItem>()` - are you not wanting to store the `items` List in realm? If you want to store that, it would need to look like this `@Persisted var items = RealmSwift.List<Item>()`

Comment: There are a number of `super.init` in your Realm objects. That can be a bit tricky as Realm objects need `self.init` so you may want to change those up to `convenience init` with `self.init` as the first line within the function. They will add more clarity to the code and enable you to supply different types of initialization on objects if needed. Also, when an object is instantiated, class vars, like `@Persisted var items = RealmSwift.List<Item>()` are as well. Your code seems to reinitialize objects that are already initialized, any reason for that?